# To find limit points of $F = \{ \frac{n}{1+x} : 0 \leq x <1 \}$

Tags: real-analysis

I need to find limit points of $F$ ,  Given $F = \{ \frac{n}{1+x} : 0 \leq x <1 \}$, $n \in \Bbb N$. According to me there is no limit point as large values of $n$ are not getting close at any number, but I am not sure.  Kindly help me with this, thanks.

[image]

Comment: Please check the edits made to your question and confirm that the new question is what you originally intended to ask.  Specifically, I wasn't sure if you were writing $\frac{n}{1} + x$ or $\frac{n}{1 + x}$.  I went with the latter.

Comment: @user46944 edit is finethanks

Comment: In the definition of $\;F\;$ , are $\;x\,,\,n\;$ variable or fixed? One and one, or what?

Comment: @Timbuc please see the edit

Answer (score 0):

***Hints:***

- I think in this context $n$ is fixed. Or an ideal way to ask the question would be to find the limit points of the set $F_n$ for some $n \in \Bbb N$.
- Now, what are the limit points of the set $\{x \ | \ 0 \le  x \lt 1 \} = [0,1)$?
- Let $c$ be a limit point of $[0,1)$ and let $(x_m)$ be the corresponding sequence in $[0,1)$ which converges to it. Think about the sequence $ \left({\dfrac{n}{1 + x_m}}\right)  $

Comment: How do you know $\;n\;$ is fixed ?

Comment: @Timbuc: That't how I interpreted the language of the question. Seemed straightforward to me.

Comment: @Is Perhaps you're right, yet I asked the OP and he hasn't yet answered.

Comment: @Timbuc the elements of set F are generated by varying values of nwhile denominator is fixed

Comment: Sorry i stated question as it is

Comment: I am editing question .posting original

Comment: @Ishfaaq what do you say

Comment: @godonichia: Going from what I read $n$ is the variable in $E$ but $x$ is the  variable in $F$ and $n$ is a *constant* in $F$. Answer addresses this. Take a look at the hints and give it a shot.

Comment: @Ishfaaq you are correct , i thinknis fixed here .

Comment: I think Ishfaaq is right, yet I posted an answer based on what you said about $\;x\;$ fixed and $\;n\;$ variable over the naturals.

Comment: @Ishfaaq can you please elaborate . Doesnt it depend upon valueof n big or large

Comment: @Ishfaaq denomiator is always between 1 and 2

Comment: @godonichia and then in fact we have $\;F=\left(\frac n2\,,\,n\right]\;$ , and thus Ishfaaq's answer is a good hint.

Comment: @Timbuc i amnot getting point

Comment: What are you not getting, @godonichia ? If $\;n\;$ is fixed and $\;x\;$ ranges between $\;0\;$ and $\;1\;$ , **not** containing the right point, then I think the above is obvious, isn't it?

Comment: The interval you have written is ok , but i am not been able to reach toco conclusion and about hint

Answer (score 0):

We have

$$\;F_x:=\left\{\;\frac n{1+x}\;:\;x\in [0,1]\;\text{fixed}\;,\;\;n=1,2,...\in\Bbb N\right\}$$

and then you're right: there are no limit *points* in $\;F_x\;$ since

$$\forall x\in [0,1]\;,\;\;\frac n{1+x}\xrightarrow[n\to\infty]{}\infty$$